# replace column header for multiple tab delimited files

Tags: unix, awk

I have more than 100 tab-delimited files with same column names. I would like to change one of the column names (column 2) from 'OLD' to 'NEW' in all the files in batch. Rest of the contents remains same in the files.
Can anyone help me how to do it with awk?

eg. file.txt

```
INFO    OLD    CONF     DB     COSMIC
NA      NA      9       .       53
NA      NA      10      .       192
NA      NA      8       .       41
NA      NA      8       .       87
NA      NA      8       .       94
NA      NA      8       .       92
NA      NA      10      .       192
NA      NA      10      .       47
NA      NA      10      .       87
```

I would like to change 'OLD' to 'NEW':

```
   INFO    NEW    CONF     DB      COSMIC
    NA      NA      9       .       53
    NA      NA      10      .       192
    NA      NA      8       .       41
    NA      NA      8       .       87
    NA      NA      8       .       94
    NA      NA      8       .       92
    NA      NA      10      .       192
    NA      NA      10      .       47
    NA      NA      10      .       87
```

I have tried the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in 'ls PATH';
do
     awk 'NR==1 && $2=="OLD"{$2=="NEW"}1' $file > temp && mv temp $file
done
```

Comment: An example will help to get more answers.

Comment: What is the delimiter? Any white space, tab only?

Comment: It is a tab delimited file containing three columns "name" "new" "value". I am not able to provide the sample data in a tabular format here. Could you suggest how to do that?

Comment: A example file has been added now in the main post above.

Comment: `$2=="NEW"` should be `$2="NEW"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do this in `sed`

```
$ sed -i'.bak' -r '1s/([^\t]*\t)OLD/\1NEW/' file
```

if you want to in place change the files, `sed` is a better alternative.  You can do all in a loop

```
$ for f in files; do sed -i'.bak' -r ... $f; done
```

`awk` alternative can be

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 && $2=="OLD"{$2="NEW"}1' file > temp && mv temp file
```

Comment: mv: missing destination file operand after `temp'

Comment: there shouldn't be a redirection there, fixed.

Comment: I have now added an example test file and intended out file, with a code. I have edited the main post on the top. Can you have a look?